# Arrow instead of a line in Forest parse trees

Tags: forest

Is there a way to obtain an arrow instead of a line connecting nodes in syntactic parse trees using forest? E.g. an arrow pointing from A to C in

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
   for tree={
   inner sep=0.25pt, s sep=5pt, 
   fit=band,
   },
   },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
   }

\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}nice empty nodes, for tree={l sep=1em,l=0,calign angle=60}
[A [B] [C]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I haven't found an obvious way to do it in the forest manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
   for tree={
   inner sep=0.25pt,
   s sep=5pt,
   fit=band,
   edge={semithick, line cap=round, red!50}% <--- settings for all edges
   },
   },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
   }

\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    nice empty nodes,
    for tree={l sep=1em, l=0, calign angle=60}
[A [B] [C,edge+={->} % <--- this edges is arrow
        ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need arrows to replace only specific lines in particular diagrams. Like I wrote in my question, only e.g. an arrow from A to C, not from A to B. -- I've now managed to do it for a particular nodes by adding `edge={->}` after the target node. Thanks!

Comment: @oliver, corrected.

Comment: `edge+={->}` would be better @oliver.

Comment: @cfr I don't seem to see a difference in the output...

Comment: @oliver Try adding `edge={thick, blue}` to the preamble of your tree and you'll see why adding is better. `edge+` adds to the existing options, whereas `edge` replaces. Here, there are no other options specified for edges, so you'll see no difference, but if you later style the edges for the whole tree, you want the defaults to apply to the arrowed ones, too.

Comment: @cfr, thank you very much for your comments. i consider them in answer. meanwhile i check `forest` documentation ... but i didn't find anything about `edge+` or meaning of the `+` extension of `forest` macro. where i can find this?

Comment: @oliver, what you means with "I'm marking this as solved"? if my answer solve your problem (on the best way) you can accept it :-)

Comment: @Zarko yes, of course, your answer is marked as "accepted" :)

Comment: @oliver, sory, but so far you not accept it (by click on check mark at top left side of answer).